# State change doesn't overwrite template

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm adding a date-picker to a mobile platform. I've made a directive in which there is a date-picker and want to be able to show it by going to certain state.

State change is successful, but the date-picker isn't shown. I've got a logger on `$stateChangeError` which doesn't log anything. *Logs of succesfull state change: [nextState & prevState](http://puu.sh/p6Mf2/ba3052fe6f.png)*.

StateChange is initiated with a `ui-sref="i.settings.account.date"` I've triple checked url's templates, but I cannot pinpoint the issue here.

$stateProvider:

```
.state('i.settings', {
        url: '/settings',
        templateUrl: templateRoot + 'me/settings/settings.html',
        controller: 'MobileSettingsController',
        order: 1,
        data: {
            header: {
                name: 'mobile.header.settings'
            }
        }
    })
.state('i.settings.account', {
        url: '/account',
        templateUrl: templateRoot + 'me/settings/account.html',
        controller: 'MobileAccountSettingsController',
        order: 2,
        resolve: {
            Settings: function (account)
            {
                return account.settings();
            }
        }
    })
    .state('i.settings.account.date', {
        url: '/date',
        templateUrl: templateRoot + 'common/directives/pfMobileDatepicker/datepicker.html',
        order: 3
    })
```

Using angular 1.4

EDIT:
Just figured out that the whole `MobileSettingsController` is not instantiated. The controller is available in the sources when viewing from the web browser though...

EDIT 2:
As in the answer I posted, I worked around the problem. If someone could tell me why this happened it would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by changing the position form `i.settings.account` to `date`. This way it is univerialy available to the whole project.

So technically this is a workaround and I did not fix the core of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have missed the controller in 'i.settings.account.date' , That might be causing the issue. Instead of directive, could you please write following code in controller to test if at all datepicker is getting shown or not :

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', 
function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){ 
    // do something
})
```

Comment: The stateChange is succesfull, there is a link of a screenshot of the logs in my OP.